# KMM Application iproject templates not displayed

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I set up trying to develop KMM development on Ubuntu 20.04 Android Studio 4.1.
The setup was done according to the procedure on the following site.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html

When I restart Android Studio, I don't see the KMM application project template.

OS: Ubuntu x64 20.04 LTS
Java:
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
　OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
　OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
Android Studio: 4.1.1

Is the setting insufficient?

Comment: check in your plugins section if your Kotlin Multiplaform Mobile plugin is enable or not.

Comment: Hello, I'd say this is caused by all KMM plugin's templates aim for generations iOS-Android modules. The iOS part hardly relies on the Xcode, and cannot be obtained on a platform different than OSX. I've found similar issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43528

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, the adoption of Kotlin / Native was NG in the project, and I could not confirm it after that.
When the project settles down, I will try again.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue after having updated all my stack: Android Studio, the KMM plugin and Kotlin. Any leads?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have "Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile" plugin installed and up to date.

[image]